# HoursBetweenUpdateChecks on UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

HoursBetweenUpdateChecks is a variable inside a UWP csproj. The current value is set to 0. The possible values there are hours between checks for updates, but does 0 mean there won't be any checks? or will it be checking constantly?

```
<AppInstallerUpdateFrequency>0</AppInstallerUpdateFrequency>
<AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency>OnApplicationRun</AppInstallerCheckForUpdateFrequency>
<HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appinstallerschema/element-onlaunch#attributes), the `HoursBetweenUpdateChecks` attribute specifies the frequency with which the deployment service will check for an update to the App Installer file. When `HoursBetweenUpdateChecks` is set to 0, the deployment service will check for updates every time the application is launched.

Comment: is there any flag in .csproj that will remove <UpdateSettings> section from .appInstaller ?